# differential equation deriving power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Derive a power series expansion about x = 0 of a general solution to
$$x^2 y''+xy'+(x-2)y=0$$
Write out the general solution with the ﬁrst three terms in each series where possible.

If we let $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ and then find $y'$ and $y''$ by this sum and then sub it into the main equation.
All the coefficients of $x^0,x^1,x^2,.....$ seem to be zero after you compare. How can you get the terms then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tryss is right, your ODE is of the Fuchsian type, in a neighbourhood of zero the only analytic solution is the zero solution. Anyway, by solving the indicial equation we have that solutions of the form:

$$ f_1(x) = x^{\sqrt{2}} g(x),\qquad f_2(x)=x^{-\sqrt{2}} h(x) $$
with $g,h\in C^{\omega}((0,\varepsilon))$ exist. It is worth to look for the coefficients of $g$ and $h$, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ be such a solution

You have

$$x^2y'' + xy' + (x-2)y = 0$$

$$x^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\right)'' + x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\right)' + (x-2)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\right) = 0$$

Then

$$x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_{n}  x^{n-2} + x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n}  x^{n-1}  + (x-2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = 0$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_{n}  x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n}  x^n  + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2a_n x^{n} = 0$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_{n}  x^n + a_1x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} na_{n}  x^n  + a_0x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^n - 2a_0 - 2a_1 x - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2a_n x^{n} = 0$$

$$-2a_0 + \left( a_0- a_1  \right) x  + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( n(n-1)a_{n}+na_n+a_{n-1}-2a_n \right) x^n = 0$$

Then you get the following system :

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array} .a_0 & = & 0 \\ 
a_0-a_1 &= &0 \\
 n(n-1)a_{n}+na_n+a_{n-1}-2a_n & =&  0\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array} .a_0 & = & 0 \\ 
a_1 &= &0 \\
 a_{n}& =&  -\frac{a_{n-1}}{n(n-1)+n-2}\end{array}\right.$$

So it seems you're right and the only solution that has a power expension is the null solution

Comment: So how would you write the final answer?

Comment: Something like "We have proven that if y is a solution with a power expension at 0, then it's the null solution. It imply that if there exist non-null solutions at this equation, they do not admit a power serie expension at 0".

Comment: can someone give a solution using Frobenius method because I think that is how you have to do it.